# Big-endian conversion in JVM

Tags: java, jvm, endianness, jvm-hotspot

AFAIK, java stores ints in memory in big-endian format. And my intel processor uses little-endian.

Where does the conversion takes place? Does it take place? How JVM developers settle performance issues?

Comment: What do you mean by "stores" here? Are you thinking of `DataInput`/`DataOutput`? If so, that's just a matter of IO. It has no connection to the internal data representation, any more than it matters that a text file is UTF-8 when you read it into a Java String.

Comment: Java doesn't specify how ints are stored in memory; the implementation may choose to store in whatever format it likes.

Comment: It would be astounding if any JVM stored int big endian on a little endian machine. Perf would be appalling.

Comment: Unrelated, but you might mean AFAIK.

Comment: Java is endian agnostic.

Comment: I meant "stores in memory". But now it's clear. The way jvm stores values may not match with java language specifications.

Comment: Another thing to consider is how binary I/O is handled. Check out the class java.nio.ByteOrder

Comment: The Java language HAS NO SPECIFICATION as to how the data is stored.  The only place where it's significant is with some of the esoteric storage-mapped interfaces, which are off-limits to mere mortals.

Comment: Well, here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html they say, that "int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer". So, it's about how should I imagine it? Or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JVM running on your Intel stores `int` as little-endian.

Comment: May I use your answer to ask one more small question? If JVM is little-endian, than bit-shift operations must be more complex, than they look?

Comment: @Oroboros102: No, the Big Endian vs Little Endian story is about how the data is stored in memory or on disk. But the arithmetic happens inside the CPU using registers. The semantic of a bit shifting operation doesn’t change.

Comment: @Oroboros102 Assuming your machine has 32-bit registers, bitshifting would likely directly result in a processor instruction on a 32-bit register, regardless of architecture.  A left-shift always moves bits toward the more significant bit, regardless of endianess.